# Different behavior among explicit cast, direct initialization and copy initialization

Tags: c++, templates, casting, initialization, language-lawyer

I have a class `C` which has a casting operator to anything. In the example I tried to cast an instance of it to `std::string` in three different ways: `static_cast`, constructor of `std::string` and assigning to `std::string`. However, only the last one compiles, while the others raise an error of ambiguous constructor.

The reason of the error is clear enough: there are many ways to convert `C` to something which the constructor of `std::string` can accept. But what is the difference between these cases? Why cast operator works as intended here but not there?

```
struct C {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const {
        return T{};
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;

    cout << static_cast<string>(c) << endl; // compile error
    string bad(c); // compile error
    string ok = c; // compiles successfully
}
```

**UPD**: as bolov mentioned in comments, this issue doesn't reproduce with C++17. I tested it with g++-5 and clang-3.8 with -std=c++11 and -std=c++14, and it shows the described errors.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/g/ESR8cw

Comment: @bolov strangely enough, but it doesn't reproduce in C++17. It reproduces at godbolt with -std=c++11. I'll add it to the post, thanks.

Comment: hmm.. interesting

Comment: @bolov Doesn't compile on gcc/clang on my side, see e.g. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98b71e48f758054a). And yes indeed g++ -std=c++17 accepts the code.

Comment: @vsoftco Nope. If you add `operator const char*` as well, the ambiguity returns. No templates now.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov I edited the title because `string ok = c;` is not assignment, but copy initialization indeed; whose initializer consists of an equals sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Before C++17**

`static_cast<string>(c)` and `string bad(c)` performs [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), then

> the constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

As you said, all the possible constructors of `std::string` are examined and `C` can be converted to anything required, then causes ambiguity.

`string ok = c` performs [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (note it's not assignment), then

> If `T` is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is not `T` or derived from `T`, or if `T` is non-class type, but the type of `other` is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of `other` to `T` (or to a type derived from `T` if `T` is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

That means the conversion from `C` to `std::string` is examined, and used for the initialization here.

**After C++17**

Since C++17 for [direct initlizatioin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization),

> if the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as `T`, the initializer expression itself, rather that a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17)

That means the conversion from `C` to `std::string` is perferred and used for the initialization, then the ambiguity disappears and the code works well.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xNqShpO4uCfVEgAd)

Comment: To elaborate on the copy initialization ([over.ics.user]/3): *If the user-defined conversion is specified by a specialization of a conversion function template, the second
standard conversion sequence shall have exact match rank.* I wouldn't say it's preferred so much as required.