# Specialize cast operator based on type traits

Tags: c++, casting, template-meta-programming, sfinae

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740341/).

I have a class with a cast operator to anything. In a pre-C++17 environment this yields errors of being unable to select appropriate constructor overload while performing initialization. I want to tune the behavior by marking the cast operator `explicit` for some types. However, I cannot find a way to do so.

Here is an artificial example: I want an implicit cast operator to integer types and explicit to all other types.

This doesn't work because we cannot determine `U` having the expression of type `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type`:

```
struct C {
    template<typename U>
    operator typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type() const {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename U>
    explicit operator typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type() const {
        return 1.5;
    }
};
```

This one fails to compile saying that `C::operator U() cannot be overloaded`:

```
struct C {
    template<typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type>
    operator U() const {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<U>::value, U>::type>
    explicit operator U() const {
        return 1.5;
    }
};
```

I cannot declare the function of kind `template<typename U, typename = void> operator U();` and partially specialize it because partial function specialization is not allowed and making a helper class looks like an overkill to me.

How can I declare cast operator based on some traits of the type I'm casting to?

I need a C++11 solution, as in C++17 the issue from my previous question is already [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46740530/2159939).b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move definitions of these operators to the base classes. This approach allows you put constraints on both implicit and explicit operators:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TDerived> class
t_ImplicitlyConvertableToAnything
{
    public: template
    <
        typename TTarget
    ,   typename TEnabled = typename ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_integral<TTarget>::value>
    >
    operator TTarget(void) const
    {
        auto const & self{static_cast<const TDerived &>(*this)};
        return(self.template CheckedConversion_To_Integral<TTarget>());
    }
};

template<typename TDerived> class
t_ExplicitlyConvertableToAnything
{
    public: template
    <
        typename TTarget
    ,   typename TEnabled = typename ::std::enable_if_t<!::std::is_integral<TTarget>::value>
    > explicit
    operator TTarget(void) const
    {
        auto const & self{static_cast<const TDerived &>(*this)};
        return(self.template CheckedConversion_To_NonIntegral<TTarget>());
    }
};

class
t_ConvertableToAnything
:   public t_ImplicitlyConvertableToAnything<t_ConvertableToAnything>
,   public t_ExplicitlyConvertableToAnything<t_ConvertableToAnything>
{
    public: template<typename TTarget> decltype(auto)
    CheckedConversion_To_Integral(void) const
    {
        return(static_cast<TTarget>(1));
    }

    public: template<typename TTarget> decltype(auto)
    CheckedConversion_To_NonIntegral(void) const
    {
        return(static_cast<TTarget>(3.14));
    }
};


int main()
{
    t_ConvertableToAnything c;
    ::std::cout << ([](int x){return(x);})(c) << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << static_cast<float>(c) << ::std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

[Run this code online](https://ideone.com/zqbRk2)

Comment: This is quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-type template parameters to avoid the "cannot be overloaded" issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A { };
struct B { };

struct C {
    template <typename U,
              typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit operator U() const {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename U,
     typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, A>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit operator U() const {
        return A{ };
    }

     template<typename U,
     typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, B>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit operator U() const {
        return B{ };
    }

};

int main() {
    C c;
    long y = static_cast<int>(c);
    B b = static_cast<B>(c);
    A a = static_cast<A>(c);
}
```

https://ideone.com/smfPwF

Answer (score 1):

You can overload your cast operator using a trick with dummy template parameters for disambiguation.

```
struct C {
    template<typename U, 
             typename = typename enable_if<is_integral<U>::value, U>::type, 
             int = 0> // <== hete
    operator U() const {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename U, 
             typename = typename enable_if<!is_integral<U>::value, U>::type, 
             char = 0> //  <== and here
    explicit operator U() const {
        return 1.5;
    }
};
```

Since the template signatures are now different, there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just leave off the constraints on the explicit operator since it covers all cases that the first operator does not.

Coliru example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d0bc6e59ece55cf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct C {
    template <typename U,
              typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<U>::value>::type>
    operator U() const {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename U, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit operator U() const {
        return 1.5;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    int v = c;
    int w = c;
    int x = static_cast<int>(c);
    long y = static_cast<int>(c);
    double z = static_cast<double>(c);

    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to @Jodocus for enabling explicit casts to integral types.

Comment: hope you don't mind I took the liberty of improving the format (no horizontal scroll), and removed useless default arg for `enable_if`

Comment: Not at all. I appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Adding a 

typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr

as second template parameter of the explicit operator overload will make the program support "unnecessary" explicit casts s.t.

int z = static_cast<int>(c);

Right now, this would be an ambiguous call, but writing out casts explicitly should always be allowed imho.

Comment: @Jodocus I agree those should be supported. I'll look at it when I get home,  but feel free to make the fix if you're sure it compiles and works. Thanks for the input.